# Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=,

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Got this error and facing a bit because the alias but my head just turning around with stuffs, could you help me to solve the alias wrong check this

```
SELECT B.PARTS_NO, B.Adj_Date, B.COST, B.ADJ_DESC, ADJ_FG_QTY_PREV = SUM(B.ADJ_FG_QTY_PREV), ADJ_COGS_QTY_PREV = SUM(B.ADJ_COGS_QTYPREV) , ADJ_FG_QTY = SUM(B.ADJ_FG_QTY), ADJ_COGS_QTY = SUM(B.ADJ_COGS_QTY)
 FROM 
 (                                                      
 SELECT                                                         
 PARTS_NO=a.PARTS_NO,                                                       
 Adj_Date=Convert(varchar(10),a.PROCESSING_DATETIME,105),                                                       
 COST=ISNULL((SELECT CASE WHEN MONTH(Convert(Datetime,LTRIM(RTRIM(@Period))+'01',112))=1 THEN ISNULL(a.ECOST_01,0)                                                      
    WHEN MONTH(Convert(Datetime,LTRIM(RTRIM(@Period))+'01',112))=2 THEN ISNULL(a.ECOST_02,0)                                                    
    WHEN MONTH(Convert(Datetime,LTRIM(RTRIM(@Period))+'01',112))=3 THEN ISNULL(a.ECOST_03,0)                                                    
    WHEN MONTH(Convert(Datetime,LTRIM(RTRIM(@Period))+'01',112))=4 THEN ISNULL(a.ECOST_04,0)                                                    
    WHEN MONTH(Convert(Datetime,LTRIM(RTRIM(@Period))+'01',112))=5 THEN ISNULL(a.ECOST_05,0)                                                    
    WHEN MONTH(Convert(Datetime,LTRIM(RTRIM(@Period))+'01',112))=6 THEN ISNULL(a.ECOST_06,0)                                                    
    WHEN MONTH(Convert(Datetime,LTRIM(RTRIM(@Period))+'01',112))=7 THEN ISNULL(a.ECOST_07,0)                                                    
    WHEN MONTH(Convert(Datetime,LTRIM(RTRIM(@Period))+'01',112))=8 THEN ISNULL(a.ECOST_08,0)                                                    
    WHEN MONTH(Convert(Datetime,LTRIM(RTRIM(@Period))+'01',112))=9 THEN ISNULL(a.ECOST_09,0)                                                    
    WHEN MONTH(Convert(Datetime,LTRIM(RTRIM(@Period))+'01',112))=10 THEN ISNULL(a.ECOST_10,0)                                                   
    WHEN MONTH(Convert(Datetime,LTRIM(RTRIM(@Period))+'01',112))=11 THEN ISNULL(a.ECOST_11,0)                                                   
    WHEN MONTH(Convert(Datetime,LTRIM(RTRIM(@Period))+'01',112))=12 THEN ISNULL(a.ECOST_12,0)                                                   
    ELSE 0                                                  
   END                                                                      
FROM TITEMBALANCE a                                                         
WHERE a.[YEAR]=YEAR(Convert(Datetime,LTRIM(RTRIM(@Period))+'01',112))                                                       
AND a.PARTS_NO=a.PARTS_NO),0),      
 ADJ_DESC ='CATS',                                              
 ADJ_FG_QTY_PREV=SUM(CASE WHEN Convert(numeric(6,0),Convert(varchar(6),a.PROCESSING_DATETIME,112))<>ISNULL(a.COSTING1,0) THEN (CASE WHEN Left(Ltrim(b.REASON_CODE),1)='1' THEN b.QUANTITY_F Else 0 End) else 0 end),                                                        
 ADJ_COGS_QTYPREV=SUM(CASE WHEN Convert(numeric(6,0),Convert(varchar(6),a.PROCESSING_DATETIME,112))<>ISNULL(a.COSTING1,0) THEN (CASE WHEN Left(Ltrim(b.REASON_CODE),1)='2' THEN b.QUANTITY_F Else 0 End) else 0 end),                                                       
 ADJ_FG_QTY=SUM(CASE WHEN Convert(numeric(6,0),Convert(varchar(6),a.PROCESSING_DATETIME,112))=ISNULL(a.COSTING1,0) THEN (CASE WHEN Left(Ltrim(b.REASON_CODE),1)='1' THEN b.QUANTITY_F Else 0 End) else 0 end),                                                      
 ADJ_COGS_QTY=SUM(CASE WHEN Convert(numeric(6,0),Convert(varchar(6),a.PROCESSING_DATETIME,112))=ISNULL(a.COSTING1,0) THEN (CASE WHEN Left(Ltrim(b.REASON_CODE),1)='2' THEN b.QUANTITY_F Else 0 End) else 0 end)                                                                                             
 FROM TPARTADJUSTMENTC a  INNER JOIN TPARTADJUSTMENTCL b ON a.CARD_NO=b.CARD_NO AND a.INHOUSE_OUTSIDE=b.INHOUSE_OUTSIDE AND a.PARTS_NO=b.PARTS_NO AND a.PROCESS_CODE=b.PROCESS_CODE AND a.FILLER=b.FILLER AND a.PROCESSING_DATETIME=b.PROCESSING_DATETIME                                                       
 WHERE ISNULL(a.COSTING1,0)=Convert(numeric(6,0),@Period)                                                       
 GROUP BY a.PARTS_NO,Convert(varchar(10),a.PROCESSING_DATETIME,105),Left(Ltrim(b.REASON_CODE),1)                                                        
 UNION ALL                                                      
 SELECT                                                         
 PARTS_NO=a.PARTS_NO,                                                       
 Adj_Date=Convert(varchar(10),a.PROCESSING_DATETIME,105),                                                       
 COST=ISNULL((SELECT CASE WHEN MONTH(Convert(Datetime,LTRIM(RTRIM(@Period))+'01',112))=1 THEN ISNULL(a.ECOST_01,0)                                                      
    WHEN MONTH(Convert(Datetime,LTRIM(RTRIM(@Period))+'01',112))=2 THEN ISNULL(a.ECOST_02,0)                                                    
    WHEN MONTH(Convert(Datetime,LTRIM(RTRIM(@Period))+'01',112))=3 THEN ISNULL(a.ECOST_03,0)                                                    
    WHEN MONTH(Convert(Datetime,LTRIM(RTRIM(@Period))+'01',112))=4 THEN ISNULL(a.ECOST_04,0)                                                    
    WHEN MONTH(Convert(Datetime,LTRIM(RTRIM(@Period))+'01',112))=5 THEN ISNULL(a.ECOST_05,0)                                                    
    WHEN MONTH(Convert(Datetime,LTRIM(RTRIM(@Period))+'01',112))=6 THEN ISNULL(a.ECOST_06,0)                                                    
    WHEN MONTH(Convert(Datetime,LTRIM(RTRIM(@Period))+'01',112))=7 THEN ISNULL(a.ECOST_07,0)                                                    
    WHEN MONTH(Convert(Datetime,LTRIM(RTRIM(@Period))+'01',112))=8 THEN ISNULL(a.ECOST_08,0)                                                    
    WHEN MONTH(Convert(Datetime,LTRIM(RTRIM(@Period))+'01',112))=9 THEN ISNULL(a.ECOST_09,0)                                                    
    WHEN MONTH(Convert(Datetime,LTRIM(RTRIM(@Period))+'01',112))=10 THEN ISNULL(a.ECOST_10,0)                                                   
    WHEN MONTH(Convert(Datetime,LTRIM(RTRIM(@Period))+'01',112))=11 THEN ISNULL(a.ECOST_11,0)                                                   
    WHEN MONTH(Convert(Datetime,LTRIM(RTRIM(@Period))+'01',112))=12 THEN ISNULL(a.ECOST_12,0)                                                   
    ELSE 0                                                  
   END                                                                      
FROM TITEMBALANCE a                                                         
WHERE a.[YEAR]=YEAR(Convert(Datetime,LTRIM(RTRIM(@Period))+'01',112))                                                       
AND a.PARTS_NO=a.PARTS_NO),0),
 ADJ_DESC ='IMPULSE',                                                                                                                   
 ADJ_FG_QTYPREV=SUM(CASE WHEN Convert(numeric(6,0),Convert(varchar(6),a.PROCESSING_DATETIME,112))<>ISNULL(a.COSTING1,0) THEN (CASE WHEN Left(Ltrim(b.REASON_CODE),1)='1' THEN b.QUANTITY_F Else 0 End) else 0 end),                                                     
 ADJ_COGS_QTYPREV=SUM(CASE WHEN Convert(numeric(6,0),Convert(varchar(6),a.PROCESSING_DATETIME,112))<>ISNULL(a.COSTING1,0) THEN (CASE WHEN Left(Ltrim(b.REASON_CODE),1)='2' THEN b.QUANTITY_F Else 0 End) else 0 end),                                                       
 ADJ_FG_QTY=SUM(CASE WHEN Convert(numeric(6,0),Convert(varchar(6),a.PROCESSING_DATETIME,112))=ISNULL(a.COSTING1,0) THEN (CASE WHEN Left(Ltrim(b.REASON_CODE),1)='1' THEN b.QUANTITY_F Else 0 End) else 0 end),                                                      
 ADJ_COGS_QTY=SUM(CASE WHEN Convert(numeric(6,0),Convert(varchar(6),a.PROCESSING_DATETIME,112))=ISNULL(a.COSTING1,0) THEN (CASE WHEN Left(Ltrim(b.REASON_CODE),1)='2' THEN b.QUANTITY_F Else 0 End) else 0 end)                                                             
 FROM TPARTADJUSTMENTI a  INNER JOIN TPARTADJUSTMENTIL b ON a.CARD_NO=b.CARD_NO AND a.INHOUSE_OUTSIDE=b.INHOUSE_OUTSIDE AND a.PARTS_NO=b.PARTS_NO AND a.PROCESS_CODE=b.PROCESS_CODE AND a.FILLER=b.FILLER AND a.PROCESSING_DATETIME=b.PROCESSING_DATETIME                                                       
 WHERE ISNULL(a.COSTING1,0)=Convert(numeric(6,0),@Period)                                                       
 GROUP BY a.PARTS_NO,Convert(varchar(10),a.PROCESSING_DATETIME,105),Left(Ltrim(b.REASON_CODE),1)                                                        

 ) B GROUP BY B.PARTS_NO, B.Adj_Date, B.COST, B.ADJ_DESC
```

Comment: Try formmating the thing to have a better look onto it.

Comment: Can you play around with the query and remove anything that doesn't cause the problem? It'll help you to pinpoint the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the alias `a` for both `TITEMBALANCE` in the subquery and `TPARTADJUSTMENTC` in the query.

I think that the condition `a.PARTS_NO=a.PARTS_NO` is supposed to compare fields from both tables, but because of the conflicting aliases it will just compare a field to itself and the query will return all parts. That will make the subquery return more than one record, and you get that error message.

Answer (score 0):

This might help the answer, I changed 2 name alias between 2 union. Thanks everyone

```
SELECT @ProsesPeriode as TanggalPeriod , B.PARTS_NO, B.Adj_Date, B.COST, B.ADJ_DESC, ADJ_FG_QTY_PREV = SUM(B.ADJ_FG_QTY_PREV), ADJ_COGS_QTY_PREV = SUM(B.ADJ_COGS_QTYPREV) , ADJ_FG_QTY = SUM(B.ADJ_FG_QTY), ADJ_COGS_QTY = SUM(B.ADJ_COGS_QTY)
 FROM 
 (                                                      
 SELECT                                                         
 PARTS_NO=d.PARTS_NO,                                                       
 Adj_Date=Convert(varchar(10),d.PROCESSING_DATETIME,105),                                                       
 COST=ISNULL((SELECT CASE WHEN MONTH(Convert(Datetime,LTRIM(RTRIM(@Period))+'01',112))=1 THEN ISNULL(a.ECOST_01,0)                                                      
    WHEN MONTH(Convert(Datetime,LTRIM(RTRIM(@Period))+'01',112))=2 THEN ISNULL(a.ECOST_02,0)                                                    
    WHEN MONTH(Convert(Datetime,LTRIM(RTRIM(@Period))+'01',112))=3 THEN ISNULL(a.ECOST_03,0)                                                    
    WHEN MONTH(Convert(Datetime,LTRIM(RTRIM(@Period))+'01',112))=4 THEN ISNULL(a.ECOST_04,0)                                                    
    WHEN MONTH(Convert(Datetime,LTRIM(RTRIM(@Period))+'01',112))=5 THEN ISNULL(a.ECOST_05,0)                                                    
    WHEN MONTH(Convert(Datetime,LTRIM(RTRIM(@Period))+'01',112))=6 THEN ISNULL(a.ECOST_06,0)                                                    
    WHEN MONTH(Convert(Datetime,LTRIM(RTRIM(@Period))+'01',112))=7 THEN ISNULL(a.ECOST_07,0)                                                    
    WHEN MONTH(Convert(Datetime,LTRIM(RTRIM(@Period))+'01',112))=8 THEN ISNULL(a.ECOST_08,0)                                                    
    WHEN MONTH(Convert(Datetime,LTRIM(RTRIM(@Period))+'01',112))=9 THEN ISNULL(a.ECOST_09,0)                                                    
    WHEN MONTH(Convert(Datetime,LTRIM(RTRIM(@Period))+'01',112))=10 THEN ISNULL(a.ECOST_10,0)                                                   
    WHEN MONTH(Convert(Datetime,LTRIM(RTRIM(@Period))+'01',112))=11 THEN ISNULL(a.ECOST_11,0)                                                   
    WHEN MONTH(Convert(Datetime,LTRIM(RTRIM(@Period))+'01',112))=12 THEN ISNULL(a.ECOST_12,0)                                                   
    ELSE 0                                                  
   END                                                                      
FROM TITEMBALANCE a                                                         
WHERE a.[YEAR]=YEAR(Convert(Datetime,LTRIM(RTRIM(@Period))+'01',112))                                                       
AND a.PARTS_NO=d.PARTS_NO),0),      
 ADJ_DESC ='CATS',                                              
 ADJ_FG_QTY_PREV=SUM(CASE WHEN Convert(numeric(6,0),Convert(varchar(6),d.PROCESSING_DATETIME,112))<>ISNULL(d.COSTING1,0) THEN (CASE WHEN Left(Ltrim(b.REASON_CODE),1)='1' THEN b.QUANTITY_F Else 0 End) else 0 end),                                                        
 ADJ_COGS_QTYPREV=SUM(CASE WHEN Convert(numeric(6,0),Convert(varchar(6),d.PROCESSING_DATETIME,112))<>ISNULL(d.COSTING1,0) THEN (CASE WHEN Left(Ltrim(b.REASON_CODE),1)='2' THEN b.QUANTITY_F Else 0 End) else 0 end),                                                       
 ADJ_FG_QTY=SUM(CASE WHEN Convert(numeric(6,0),Convert(varchar(6),d.PROCESSING_DATETIME,112))=ISNULL(d.COSTING1,0) THEN (CASE WHEN Left(Ltrim(b.REASON_CODE),1)='1' THEN b.QUANTITY_F Else 0 End) else 0 end),                                                      
 ADJ_COGS_QTY=SUM(CASE WHEN Convert(numeric(6,0),Convert(varchar(6),d.PROCESSING_DATETIME,112))=ISNULL(d.COSTING1,0) THEN (CASE WHEN Left(Ltrim(b.REASON_CODE),1)='2' THEN b.QUANTITY_F Else 0 End) else 0 end)                                                                                             
 FROM TPARTADJUSTMENTC d  INNER JOIN TPARTADJUSTMENTCL b ON d.CARD_NO=b.CARD_NO AND d.INHOUSE_OUTSIDE=b.INHOUSE_OUTSIDE AND d.PARTS_NO=b.PARTS_NO AND d.PROCESS_CODE=b.PROCESS_CODE AND d.FILLER=b.FILLER AND d.PROCESSING_DATETIME=b.PROCESSING_DATETIME                                                       
 WHERE ISNULL(d.COSTING1,0)=Convert(numeric(6,0),@Period)                                                       
 GROUP BY d.PARTS_NO,Convert(varchar(10),d.PROCESSING_DATETIME,105),Left(Ltrim(b.REASON_CODE),1)                                                        
 UNION ALL                                                      
 SELECT                                                         
 PARTS_NO=k.PARTS_NO,                                                       
 Adj_Date=Convert(varchar(10),k.PROCESSING_DATETIME,105),                                                       
 COST=ISNULL((SELECT CASE WHEN MONTH(Convert(Datetime,LTRIM(RTRIM(@Period))+'01',112))=1 THEN ISNULL(a.ECOST_01,0)                                                      
    WHEN MONTH(Convert(Datetime,LTRIM(RTRIM(@Period))+'01',112))=2 THEN ISNULL(a.ECOST_02,0)                                                    
    WHEN MONTH(Convert(Datetime,LTRIM(RTRIM(@Period))+'01',112))=3 THEN ISNULL(a.ECOST_03,0)                                                    
    WHEN MONTH(Convert(Datetime,LTRIM(RTRIM(@Period))+'01',112))=4 THEN ISNULL(a.ECOST_04,0)                                                    
    WHEN MONTH(Convert(Datetime,LTRIM(RTRIM(@Period))+'01',112))=5 THEN ISNULL(a.ECOST_05,0)                                                    
    WHEN MONTH(Convert(Datetime,LTRIM(RTRIM(@Period))+'01',112))=6 THEN ISNULL(a.ECOST_06,0)                                                    
    WHEN MONTH(Convert(Datetime,LTRIM(RTRIM(@Period))+'01',112))=7 THEN ISNULL(a.ECOST_07,0)                                                    
    WHEN MONTH(Convert(Datetime,LTRIM(RTRIM(@Period))+'01',112))=8 THEN ISNULL(a.ECOST_08,0)                                                    
    WHEN MONTH(Convert(Datetime,LTRIM(RTRIM(@Period))+'01',112))=9 THEN ISNULL(a.ECOST_09,0)                                                    
    WHEN MONTH(Convert(Datetime,LTRIM(RTRIM(@Period))+'01',112))=10 THEN ISNULL(a.ECOST_10,0)                                                   
    WHEN MONTH(Convert(Datetime,LTRIM(RTRIM(@Period))+'01',112))=11 THEN ISNULL(a.ECOST_11,0)                                                   
    WHEN MONTH(Convert(Datetime,LTRIM(RTRIM(@Period))+'01',112))=12 THEN ISNULL(a.ECOST_12,0)                                                   
    ELSE 0                                                  
   END                                                                      
FROM TITEMBALANCE a                                                         
WHERE a.[YEAR]=YEAR(Convert(Datetime,LTRIM(RTRIM(@Period))+'01',112))                                                       
AND a.PARTS_NO=k.PARTS_NO),0),
 ADJ_DESC ='IMPULSE',                                                                                                                   
 ADJ_FG_QTYPREV=SUM(CASE WHEN Convert(numeric(6,0),Convert(varchar(6),k.PROCESSING_DATETIME,112))<>ISNULL(k.COSTING1,0) THEN (CASE WHEN Left(Ltrim(b.REASON_CODE),1)='1' THEN b.QUANTITY_F Else 0 End) else 0 end),                                                     
 ADJ_COGS_QTYPREV=SUM(CASE WHEN Convert(numeric(6,0),Convert(varchar(6),k.PROCESSING_DATETIME,112))<>ISNULL(k.COSTING1,0) THEN (CASE WHEN Left(Ltrim(b.REASON_CODE),1)='2' THEN b.QUANTITY_F Else 0 End) else 0 end),                                                       
 ADJ_FG_QTY=SUM(CASE WHEN Convert(numeric(6,0),Convert(varchar(6),k.PROCESSING_DATETIME,112))=ISNULL(k.COSTING1,0) THEN (CASE WHEN Left(Ltrim(b.REASON_CODE),1)='1' THEN b.QUANTITY_F Else 0 End) else 0 end),                                                      
 ADJ_COGS_QTY=SUM(CASE WHEN Convert(numeric(6,0),Convert(varchar(6),k.PROCESSING_DATETIME,112))=ISNULL(k.COSTING1,0) THEN (CASE WHEN Left(Ltrim(b.REASON_CODE),1)='2' THEN b.QUANTITY_F Else 0 End) else 0 end)                                                             
 FROM TPARTADJUSTMENTI k  INNER JOIN TPARTADJUSTMENTIL b ON k.CARD_NO=b.CARD_NO AND k.INHOUSE_OUTSIDE=b.INHOUSE_OUTSIDE AND k.PARTS_NO=b.PARTS_NO AND k.PROCESS_CODE=b.PROCESS_CODE AND k.FILLER=b.FILLER AND k.PROCESSING_DATETIME=b.PROCESSING_DATETIME                                                       
 WHERE ISNULL(k.COSTING1,0)=Convert(numeric(6,0),@Period)                                                       
 GROUP BY k.PARTS_NO,Convert(varchar(10),k.PROCESSING_DATETIME,105),Left(Ltrim(b.REASON_CODE),1)                                                        

 ) B GROUP BY B.PARTS_NO, B.Adj_Date, B.COST, B.ADJ_DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of your problem with this query is actually conflicting Aliases for Tables ItemBalance & TPartAdjustmentC.

The Same Alias (a) being used for the tables in the union All renders the condition comparing the part numbers as ambiguous.